# My input is always ignored

Tags: java, arrays, input, java.util.scanner, line

So, I'm trying to figure out why my program isnt working the right way. I want to save stuff in an array, but the first input always gets ignored. For example, I ask the user "do you want to enter more xy?" and then a yes comes, I ask how many and the users types in 2 the last one added gets ignored, the first one is showing. If its only one it doesn't even show.

Here's my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class TriangleType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a , b ,c ,result , total,count;
        int x=9;
        String triangle = null;

     String[] output=new String[110];
        //storing types of traingles and their count for the statics display
        String[][] triangleTypes={{"gleichseitig","0"} ,{"gleichschenklig","0"},{"spitzwinklig","0"},{"rechtwinklig","0"},{"stumpwinkling","0"}};
        //2D array to store the sides of a traingle
        int[][] sides=new int[110][3];
        sides[0][0]=2;   sides[0][1]=2;      sides[0][2]=4;
        sides[1][0]=3;   sides[1][1]=4;      sides[1][2]=5;
        sides[2][0]=5;   sides[2][1]=5;      sides[2][2]=5;
        sides[3][0]=8;   sides[3][1]=6;      sides[3][2]=10;
        sides[4][0]=10;  sides[4][1]=10;     sides[4][2]=2;
        sides[5][0]=2;   sides[5][1]=4;      sides[5][2]=9;
        sides[6][0]=12;  sides[6][1]=36;     sides[6][2]=4;
        sides[7][0]=5;   sides[7][1]=6;      sides[7][2]=7;
        sides[8][0]=7;   sides[8][1]=9;      sides[8][2]=12;

        //User input
        System.out.println("Moechten Sie mehr Dreiecke hinzufuegen? (1/Ja/; 0/Nein/)");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = input.nextLine();
        int equivalent=Integer.parseInt(s);
        if(equivalent==1){
            System.out.println("Wie viele Dreiecke moechten Sie hinzufuegen?");
            Scanner inputt = new Scanner(System.in);
            String ss = input.nextLine();
            total=Integer.parseInt(ss);
            for (int i=0; i<total; i++){
            System.out.println("Seite a von Dreieck   "+(8+i+1)+" eingeben:");
            Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s1 = input1.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Seite b von Dreieck   "+(8+i+1)+" eingeben:");          Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s2 = input2.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Seite c von Dreieck   "+(8+i+1)+" eingeben:");          Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String s3 = input3.nextLine();
            a=Integer.parseInt(s1);
            b=Integer.parseInt(s2);
            c=Integer.parseInt(s3);
             x=9+i;
            sides[9+i][0]=a;
            sides[9+i][1]=b;
            sides[9+i][2]=c;

        }}   

        for(int j=0; j<x; j++){
             triangle=evaluateTriangle(sides[j][0], sides[j][1], sides[j][2]);
             output[j]=triangle;

            System.out.println(sides[j][0]+" "+sides[j][1]+" "+sides[j][2] + " "+triangle);

        }
        for(int k=0; k<output.length; k++)
        {
            //check if returned triangle matches with one of defined types in triangleType array  
            for(int l=0; l<triangleTypes.length; l++ ){
                if(output[k]==triangleTypes[l][0])
                {  //if yes then update second member indicating no of occurences of that particular traingle
                 count=(Integer.parseInt(triangleTypes[l][1]));
                 count=count+1;
                 triangleTypes[l][1]=Integer.toString(count);
                }
            }


        }

        //show statistics
        System.out.println("======STATISTIK=======");
        System.out.println("Dreieckstyp  Anzahl");
        for(int m=0; m<triangleTypes.length; m++)
        {
        System.out.println(triangleTypes[m][0]+"  "+triangleTypes[m][1]);   
        }





    }
    //function to evaluate the type of triangle
    public static String evaluateTriangle(int side1 , int side2 , int side3){
        int a,b,c;
        a=side1;
        b=side2;
        c=side3;
        if(a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
        {return "kein gültiges Dreieck";}
        else if(a == b && b == c)
        {return "gleichseitiges Dreieck";}
        else if((a*a)+(b*b)==(c*c))
        {return "rechtwinkliges Dreieck";}
        else if((a*a)+(b*b)>(c*c))
        { return "spitzwinkliges Dreieck";}
        else if((a*a)+(b*b)<(c*c))
        { return "stumpwinklinges Dreieck";}
        else if (a == b || b == c || c == a)
        {return "gleichschenkliges Dreieck";}
        else return "undefiniert";


    }

}
```

Sorry for the long code but I'm desperate here (also super new to java).
Thankks in advance!

Comment: Could you translate the german sentences to english?

Comment: Everyone is desperate. Everyone wants their question to be the exception. You'll get more help if you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AlexMontoro comments? On it

Comment: @MichaelMyers so sorry, it' just I wanted to try and figure it out on my own and kinda have only a couple of mins left to upload it, so I didn't really know where to even start when posting this :/

Comment: If you say you want to add 3 more, is only the last one showing?

Comment: @StefanH If I add 3 more, the first 2 are showing, the last one gets ignored. https://puu.sh/ySWov/9c538c38c3.png

Comment: Your for loop might not be counting all the way up: for(int j=0; j<x; j++){ try <=x

Comment: YES! @StefanH That was the issue! Works perfect now! Thanks you so so much!

Comment: @AlexanderI. I posted an answer for you - glad I could help!

Comment: FYI: Don't create multiple `Scanner` objects on `System.in`. Only create one, then keep using it.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ --- A simple error like `j<x` vs `j<=x` should have been easy to find with a debugger.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, possibly, but I'm like a complete newbie and this little program took me quite some time to write, believe it or not, but I am trying to get better and appreciate the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop in your code to print the results isn't going high enough, change the for loop to have <=x:

```
for(int j=0; j<=x; j++){
             triangle=evaluateTriangle(sides[j][0], sides[j][1], sides[j][2]);
             output[j]=triangle;

            System.out.println(sides[j][0]+" "+sides[j][1]+" "+sides[j][2] + " "+triangle);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Wie viele Dreiecke moechten Sie hinzufuegen?");
Scanner inputt = new Scanner(System.in);
String ss = input.nextLine();
```

Shouldn't the last input.nextLine() be inputt.nextLine()?

It would be easier to debug if you would remove all lines that are necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: This looks it might be a bug, perhaps using more informative names will help you with issues like these - these is no logical difference between input and inputt - but addMorePrompt and numberOfNewCoordsPrompt would make this a lot clearer what the bug is.

Comment: Tried removing it completely, doesn't do it. It does nothing actually. So it's gotta be something else :/

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
        for(int j=0; j<x; j++)
```

your for loop isn't reaching the last element because you need tho reach 11 elements in an array but you only index ten of them, put:

```
        for(int j=0; j<=x; j++)
```

that way you'll reach

```
        sides[10][0]
        sides[10][1]
        sides[10][2]
```

which contains the data that is not being displayed